# Javascript bind() function

Tags: javascript, bind

I need to write a function that accepts and function and an argument and returns the bound version of the the passed in function. Why doesn't my code work?

````
function bindToAnArg(func, arg){
 

     let myFunc = func.bind(arg);


return myFunc;

}

////Test

function add(num1, num2) {
  return num1 + num2;
}

const addTwo = bindToAnArg(add, 2);

console.log(addTwo);

const twoPlusSix = addTwo(6);```
````

Comment: first argument to `bind` is the bound `this` [see docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) ... so, you'd want something like `let myFunc = func.bind(null, arg);`

Comment: Beat me to it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first argument to `func.bind(...)` must be the context (`this`) of the function. It's probably easier to avoid `Function.prototype.bind` altogether.

```js
const bind = (f, ...a) => (...b) =>
  f(...a, ...b)

const add = (a, b) =>
  a + b

const addTwo =
  bind(add, 2)

console.log("2 plus 6 equals", addTwo(6))
// 2 plus 6 equals 8

const addMany = (...all) =>
  all.reduce(add, 0)

const addSome = bind(addMany, 1, 2, 3)

console.log("1 plus 2 plus 3 plus 4 plus 5 equals", addSome(4, 5))
// 1 plus 2 plus 3 plus 4 plus 5 equals 15
```

Answer (score 0):

The first argument of `bind` is what the value of `this` will be when the function is called. You probably should just pass `null`. This could would work:

```
function bindToAnArg(func, arg) {
    return func.bind(null, arg);
}
```